# Почему Windows 10 не видит модем Yota после Linux?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, модемы

Windows 10 очень странно себя ведет, модем горит, звук подключения и отключения модема есть, но ОС не видит никаких подключений. Индикатор сети показывает, что подключений никаких нет. Когда пытаюсь создать новое подключение на windows 10, то никакие устройства и доступные подключения не высвечиваются. В диспетчере устройств никаких проблем нет, сетевой драйвер realtek стоит.

Answer (score 0):

После линукса, запускаю на Windows 8 (пишут, что с 7 тоже). Он устанавливает Remote NDIS based internet sharing и перезагружаю на Windows 10.